# pages shortcode filtering by category

Tags: wp-query, loop, pages, shortcode, taxonomy

I've created a WP shortcode to list out pages which has controls to filter via category and also two layout formats. My issue is that the shortcode is not displaying all the pages that I have marked categories against. The 'box' layout is only showing 1 page and then the loop stops. The 'list' layout shows 3/4 pages that have the category applied.

I think my main issue is getting my head around the ob_clean() and ob_start() output buffering methods. I can't seem to figure out what I am doing wrong and I've been pulling my hair out for a few hours (i.e. I've commented out OB on the list format for now).

I'm hoping someone can tell me something obvious that I am doing wrong:

```
<?php

function display_page_categories() {

    // Create unique taxonomy just for pages
    $tax = array('label' => 'Categories',
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'public' => true,
        'show_in_menu' => true, );
    register_taxonomy('pages_category', 'page', $tax);

}
// Initialise cats for pages
add_action( 'init', 'display_page_categories' );

function qut_research_pages_shortcode($atts, $content = null)
{
    $atts = qut_research_subpages_shortcode_atts($atts);

    return qut_research_subpages_shortcode_frontend($atts);
}
\add_shortcode('qut-research-subpages', __NAMESPACE__.'\qut_research_pages_shortcode');

function qut_research_subpages_shortcode_atts($atts)
{
    $defaults = array(
        'sort_by' => 'menu_order',
        'sort_order' => 'asc',
        'layout' => 'boxes',
        'category' => '',
    );

    return array_replace_recursive($defaults, $atts);
}

function qut_research_subpages_shortcode_frontend($atts)
{
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'page',
        'posts_per_page' => '-1',
    );

    if (!empty($atts['category'])) {
        $args['pages_category'] = $atts['category'];
    }

    $theme_uri = get_template_directory_uri();

    $loop = new \WP_Query($args);
    $post_featured_image = get_the_post_thumbnail_url($loop->the_post(),'thumbnail');
    $output = '';

    if ( $atts['layout'] == 'boxes' || $atts['layout'] == '' ) {

        ob_start(); ?>
        <div class="row" style="margin-top: 20px">

        <?php while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post(); ?>

                    <div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6" style="padding: 5px;">
                        <a class="project-subpage" href="<?= the_permalink(); ?>">
                            <figure class="project-box" style="height: 120px; position: relative; background-size: cover; background-image: url(
                            <?php
                            if (get_the_post_thumbnail_url($loop->the_post()) ) {
                                echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url($loop->the_post(),'thumbnail');
                            } else {
                                echo $theme_uri. '/img/qut-logo.svg';
                            }
                            ?>
                                    );">
                                <figcaption style="position: absolute; display: table; height: 35%; width: 100%; background: rgba(0,0,0,0.6); color: white; font-size: 1rem; text-align: center; left: 0; bottom: 0; ">
                                    <div class="site-title" style="display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; width: 100%; padding: 0px 10px;">
                                        <p style="margin: 0"><?= the_title(); ?></p>
                                    </div>
                                </figcaption>
                            </figure>
                        </a>
                    </div>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        </div>

    <?php $output .= ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
        return $output;
        \wp_reset_query();

    } else if ( ($atts['layout'] == 'list') ) {
        //ob_start(); ?>
        <ul style="margin-top:20px">
            <?php while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
            <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
        </ul>
    <?php }

    \wp_reset_query();
    //ob_end_clean();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

> ob_start() This function will turn output buffering on. While output
>   buffering is active no output is sent from the script (other than
>   headers), instead the output is stored in an internal buffer.
>
> ob_get_clean() Gets the current buffer contents and delete current
>   output buffer.

try this code

```
function qut_research_subpages_shortcode_frontend($atts)
{
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'page',
        'posts_per_page' => '-1',
    );

    if (!empty($atts['category'])) {
        $args['pages_category'] = $atts['category'];
    }

    $theme_uri = get_template_directory_uri();

    $loop = new \WP_Query($args);
    $post_featured_image = get_the_post_thumbnail_url($loop>the_post(),'thumbnail');

    if ( $atts['layout'] == 'boxes' || $atts['layout'] == '' ) {

        ob_start(); ?>
        <div class="row" style="margin-top: 20px">

        <?php while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post(); ?>

                    <div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6" style="padding: 5px;">
                        <a class="project-subpage" href="<?= the_permalink(); ?>">
                            <figure class="project-box" style="height: 120px; position: relative; background-size: cover; background-image: url(
                            <?php
                            if (get_the_post_thumbnail_url($loop->the_post()) ) {
                                echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url($loop->the_post(),'thumbnail');
                            } else {
                                echo $theme_uri. '/img/qut-logo.svg';
                            }
                            ?>
                                    );">
                                <figcaption style="position: absolute; display: table; height: 35%; width: 100%; background: rgba(0,0,0,0.6); color: white; font-size: 1rem; text-align: center; left: 0; bottom: 0; ">
                                    <div class="site-title" style="display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; width: 100%; padding: 0px 10px;">
                                        <p style="margin: 0"><?= the_title(); ?></p>
                                    </div>
                                </figcaption>
                            </figure>
                        </a>
                    </div>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        </div>

    <?php $output = ob_get_clean();
        return $output;
        \wp_reset_query();

    } else if ( ($atts['layout'] == 'list') ) {
        //ob_start(); ?>
        <ul style="margin-top:20px">
            <?php while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
            <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
        </ul>
    <?php }

    \wp_reset_query();
    //ob_end_clean();
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, that did clean up my code quite a bit. My actual problem was the way I was calling the featured images from the page, that was causing all kinds of issues with my code and pointing me in all kinds of false leads...

Answer (score 0):

My actual problem originated from the way I was retrieving the featured image from the page, just the php error reporting wasn't being all that clear about my mistake. Have updated my code within the `qut_research_subpages_shortcode_frontend()` function to go like:

```
                    <figure class="project-box" style="height: 120px; position: relative; background-size: cover; background-image: url(
                    <?php
                    if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                        echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url(get_the_ID(),'thumbnail');
                    } else {
                        echo $theme_uri. '/img/qut-logo.svg';
                    }
                    ?>
                        );">
```

This resolved my issue.